# Jenkins Integration with Github

Tags: git, maven, github, jenkins

I am preety new to both Jenkins and Github. I have created an AWS server running Ubuntu 14.04, on which I have installed Jenkins and the JDK for it. I have use the native build to install Jenkins (i.e. `apt-get`). I have installed the Github plugins in Jenkins and I am having an Github account having a public repository having a maven project. 
But I am having a doubt on whether I need to install Git on the Ubuntu server running Jenkins. In the Github plugin I got an option to install Git automatically.
It will be helpfull if I can get some help in building my project using Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options in which you can resolve your issue. You can install the Git on the server or you can map the plugin installed to the Jenkins system.

1. The first option is very straight forward that you just need to install the 'git' package on to the server where you have installed the Jenkins and reload/restart the Jenkins to get the changes in effect.
2. The second option is to map the installed plugin to the Jenkins system. You will see all the installed plugins in the directory "/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/".
   Go to configure system and in the path to Git executable field. Now your Jenkins should be able to init the Git.
   Happy git integration!!